# Java Reflection: Create an implementing class

Tags: java, reflection, interface

```
Class someInterface = Class.fromName("some.package.SomeInterface");
```

How do I now create a new class that implements `someInterface`?

I need to create a new class, and pass it to a function that needs a `SomeInterface` as an argument.

Comment: Creating classes on the fly is not easy at all, I'm afraid.

Comment: @MichaelMyers It's not that hard as well, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9583681/632951

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Creating something which pretends to implement an interface on the fly actually isn't too hard. You can use [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) after implementing [`InvocationHandler`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) to handle any method calls.

Of course, you could actually generate a real class with a library like [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/).

If this is for test purposes, you should look at mocking frameworks like [jMock](http://www.jmock.org/) and [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/).

Comment: Whoa, neat! I wonder what else is in the java.lang.reflect package that I don't know about?

Answer (score 96):

Easily, [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) to the rescue!

**Full working example**:

```
interface IRobot {

    String Name();

    String Name(String title);

    void Talk();

    void Talk(String stuff);

    void Talk(int stuff);

    void Talk(String stuff, int more_stuff);

    void Talk(int stuff, int more_stuff);

    void Talk(int stuff, String more_stuff);
}

public class ProxyTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        IRobot robot = (IRobot) java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                IRobot.class.getClassLoader(),
                new java.lang.Class[] { IRobot.class },
                new java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler() {

            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, java.lang.reflect.Method method, Object[] args) throws java.lang.Throwable {
                String method_name = method.getName();
                Class<?>[] classes = method.getParameterTypes();

                if (method_name.equals("Name")) {
                    if (args == null) {
                        return "Mr IRobot";
                    } else {
                        return args[0] + " IRobot";
                    }
                } else if (method_name.equals("Talk")) {
                    switch (classes.length) {
                        case 0:
                            System.out.println("Hello");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (classes[0] == int.class) {
                                System.out.println("Hi. Int: " + args[0]);
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Hi. String: " + args[0]);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (classes[0] == String.class) {
                                System.out.println("Hi. String: " + args[0] + ". Int: " + args[1]);
                            } else {
                                if (classes[1] == String.class) {
                                    System.out.println("Hi. int: " + args[0] + ". String: " + args[1]);
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Hi. int: " + args[0] + ". Int: " + args[1]);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });

        System.out.println(robot.Name());
        System.out.println(robot.Name("Dr"));
        robot.Talk();
        robot.Talk("stuff");
        robot.Talk(100);
        robot.Talk("stuff", 200);
        robot.Talk(300, 400);
        robot.Talk(500, "stuff");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good additional post to this answer: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-proxies.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go beyond interfaces, you might want to take a look at [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) and [objenesis](http://code.google.com/p/objenesis/). Together, they will allow you to do some pretty powerful stuff, extending an abstract class and instantiating it. ([jMock](http://www.jmock.org/mocking-classes.html) uses them for that purpose, for example.)

If you want to stick with interfaces, do what Jon Skeet said :).

Answer (score -4):

Actually, you have to use the class name in Class.fromName() method and cast to your interface type. See if the sample below helps.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Car ferrari = (Car) Class.forName("Mercedez").newInstance();
        System.out.println(ferrari.getName());
    }
}

interface Car {
    String getName();
}

class Mercedez implements Car {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Mercedez";
    }

}

class Ferrari implements Car {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Ferrari";
    }

}
```

Comment: This misses the point of the question. The OP's question is a little unclear, but they're looking for a way to implement a class at run time. Not simply create an object of an unknown class but effectively create a new class entirely.

Comment: it's not even close to the topic