# Override and implement method at runtime in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-library

There is a class which's method returns result with delegate pattern.

```
class A {

   interface ICallback {
     callback(String data);
   }

   void doSomeAction(ICallback cb) {
     //some manipuation
     if(cb != null) {
        cb.callback(response);
     }
  }
}
```

The problem here is that A class is in library project and it possible that library will not be attached to the main project. So, the load of A class and call of doSomeAction should be implemented with reflections. But how should proceed with callback?
I read about [Proxy](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), but I am still can not understand is it possible to solve it with Porxy. Or is there other solutions for such case?

I tried with Proxy:

```
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.aa.bb.cc.dd.A$ICallback");
        Class<?>[] interfaces = new Class[] { clazz};
        Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader(), interfaces, handler);
```

In the last line I am gettin "com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method" error.

Comment: You mean cb.callback(response), right?

Comment: @OlegGryb Yes, I'v just edited. thanks!

Comment: Where implementation of ICallback should be? Is it in the library that is not in the project or in the project? Can you take the interface out of class A and put it to a separate ICallback.java file?

Comment: the callback should be in project. No, it's a library and I can not change it.

Comment: Using `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` is the right solution. Tutorial: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-proxies.html

Comment: Suppose you can create the proxy, and you can cast it to `ICallback`. How are you going to pass the proxy to `A.doSomething` method?

Comment: You'll need to post your handler. Here is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082850/java-reflection-create-an-implementing-class

Comment: it works,thanks for your attention. I will complete and past the code.