# Android / Java - get TYPE of a hidden class via Reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am trying to use the hidden package manager method `installPackage` via reflections.

My major problem is that one of its parameters is another hidden class `android.content.pm.IPackageInstallObserver`. How can I get the **TYPE** of that class (not an instance of it)?

```
val cPackageManager = Class.forName("android.content.pm.PackageManager")
val cPackageInstallObserver = Class.forName("android.content.pm.IPackageInstallObserver")

// here I need the IPackageInstallObserver type as a parameter type to look up the method
val installPackageMethod = cPackageManager.getMethod("installPackage", Uri::class.java, cPackageInstallObserver::class.java, Integer.TYPE, String::class.java)
```

In the way above, `cPackageInstallObserver::class.java` resolves to only a `Class` but not the actual type I need.

Does anybody have a solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just did a simple mistake here

```
Uri::class.java, cPackageInstallObserver, Integer.TYPE, String::class.java)
```

As `cPackageInstallObserver` is already a class you need, as `Class.forName` returns a `Class` type, but you used `cPackageInstallObserver::class.java` so it is just same as doing `String.class.getClass()` in java, so just `Class.class`.

Comment: You were right thanks for pointing that out. Do you also know how I can create a class that implements that interface type? à la ```MyClass : cPackageInstallObserver() { /* ... */ }```

Comment: if this is an interface then lookup for Proxy classes, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397139/how-to-create-a-callback-using-reflection-in-android