# Can I use Scala's Dynamic to programmatically create an object instance of some trait?

Tags: scala, dynamic, scala-macros

I have a list of method signatures of some `trait T` given as objects, similar to the following, ignoring arity:

```
case class Method[T,A,B](name: String, f: T => A => B)
```

So given some trait `T`, this could look like:

```
trait T{
  def foo(i: Int): String
  def bar(s: String): Unit
}

def methodsOfT: Seq[Method[T,_,_]] = Seq(
  Method("foo", t => i => t.foo(i)),
  Method("bar", t => s => t.bar(s))
)
```

I want to create an instance of type `T`, or of the class associated with `T`, whatever, that uses a dictionary of `Method` objects to implement `T`'s interface.

It could look like the following (this won't compile):

```
def reify[T](impl: T, methods: Method[T,_,_]): T = (new Object with Dynamic {
  def applyDynamic(method: String)(args: Any*): Any = {
    //do something here
  }
}).asInstanceOf[T]  //<- will fail at runtime
```

Of course the returned object is of type `Object`, and cannot be cast to type/class `T`. Is there any way to work around this problem?

#### Why I want to do this

I have a trait `T` for which I want to create a remote invocation interface. On the client side, I need an instance of `T` that forwards method invocations over a network connection. I could implement this `RemoteT`. But the code is completely boilerplate.

```
new T {
  def foo(i: Int): String = 
    methodsOfT.find(_.name == "foo").get.f(i).asInstanceOf[String]
  def bar(s: String): Unit = 
    methodsOfT.find(_.name == "bar").get.f(s).asInstanceOf[Unit]
}
```

I think I could use macros to synthesize the method overrides and forward them to the network remote handler. But I'm still trying to avoid macros.

### P.S.

The following question is very related. I'm currently exploring this approach:
[Java Reflection: Create an implementing class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082850/java-reflection-create-an-implementing-class/1082869#1082869)

Answer (score 2):

I believe similar thing is done in shapeless to implement lenses.

[Here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/cb973aa10f066782e8543fdce8d44b2d83996801/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/lenses.scala#L46) you can see that dynamics delegate creation of lens to an implicit - returned type is taken from [functional depenencies](https://milessabin.com/blog/2011/07/16/fundeps-in-scala/) (here: that `mkLens.Out`)

```
trait Lens[S, A] extends LPLens[S, A] { outer =>
...
  def selectDynamic(k: String)
    (implicit mkLens: MkSelectDynamicOptic[Lens[S, A], A, Symbol @@ k.type, Nothing]): mkLens.Out = mkLens(this)
...
}
```

the Lens itself is not generated with macro, but with normal derivation, but [you can use macro](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/d2c616975c04d860b0d81162c15e196f3f9d4f1d/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/generic1.scala#L37) to generate implicit, it should be possible.

```
object Generic1 extends Generic10 {
...

  implicit def mkGeneric10[T[_], U[_], FR[_[_], _[_]]]: Generic1[T, ({ type λ[t[_]] = FR[t, U] })#λ] =
    macro Generic1Macros.mkGeneric1Impl[T, ({ type λ[t[_]] = FR[t, U] })#λ]

...
}
```

A combination of macro + dynamics is used in [HList](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/cb973aa10f066782e8543fdce8d44b2d83996801/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/hlists.scala#L116).

```
object HList extends Dynamic {
...
  /**
   * Allows to specify an `HList` type with a syntax similar to `Record` and `Union`, as follows,
   *
   * {{{
   * type ISB = HList.`Int, String, Boolean`.T
   * }}}
   *
   * Literal types are allowed, so that the following is valid,
   *
   * {{{
   * type ABC = HList.`'a, 'b, 'c`.T
   * type TwoTrueStr = HList.`2, true, "str"`.T
   * }}}
   */
  def selectDynamic(tpeSelector: String): Any = macro LabelledMacros.hlistTypeImpl
...
}
```

All in all, you should be able to achieve you goal. It all just depends on how exactly you want to instantiate you object - e.g. take implicit `ClassTag` and call constructor using reflection or maybe constructing `HList` and using `Generic` to turn it into an specific representation or maybe some something else.