# how to create generic List from java.lang.reflect.Type

Tags: java

```
public class Bar {
  private String name;
  private String id;
  ...
}
public class Foo {

    private List<Bar> list;

    ...
}

......

Field f = Foo.class.getField("list")
Type = type = f.getGenericType();
```

Here I can get a generic type of list in Foo class. But I don't know how to create List from type.
Does anyone know how to build List from java.lang.reflect.Type?

Comment: `List` is an interface, you should be creating its implementation (e.g. `ArrayList`).  Though, [it's possible to create a class implementing an interface using `Proxy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082850/java-reflection-create-an-implementing-class/9583681#9583681)

Comment: What do you mean "build"?

Comment: @AndyTurner I meant "implement" :) I wanted to make Implementation of List<Bar> from  genericType

Comment: @Bae so you want to assign a value to `list`? Why do you need reflection? `list = new ArrayList<>();`.